# Mac Excel VBA Copy/Paste Workbook to Workbook

Tags: worksheet-function, vba

Keep getting syntax error or missing ')' error.  Just want to copy from one workbook to the other.  Can you do a range with this formula ("A27:DE10000")? or do I need to do the dim, etc. type of formula?

```
Sub CopyData()

Workbooks(“COPYFROM.xlsx”).Worksheets(“ANALYSIS”).Range(“A27:DE10000”).Copy
Workbooks(“COPYTO.xlsx”).Worksheets(“ANALYSIS”).Range(“A27:DE10000”)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error can be caused by a missing line continuation character (`" _"`)

Your `Sub` contains 2 distinct lines (separated by carriage return?), when they should be on 1 line

And possibly, quotation marks: `“ANALYSIS”` vs `"ANALYSIS"`

---

.

There are different ways (and syntax) for Copy / Paste methods:

**1.** - On the same line:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")

'Or

Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")     'Without using the named parameter
```

---

**2.** - On two separate lines - `Worksheet.Paste` (not a Range method):

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy
Sheet2.Paste Destination:=Sheet2.Range("A1")      '.Paste method belongs to Worksheet
```

---

**3.** - On two separate lines - `Range.PasteSpecial`:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Copy
Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll '.PasteSpecial belongs to a Range Object
```

---

.

Your syntax is using version 1

To fix the error, and still be able to see both lines on the screen, without scrolling horizontally:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()

    Workbooks("COPYFROM.xlsx").Worksheets("ANALYSIS").Range("A27:DE10000").Copy _
        Workbooks("COPYTO.xlsx").Worksheets("ANALYSIS").Range("A27:DE10000")

End Sub
```

Or

```
Public Sub CopyData()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Set wsSource = Workbooks("COPYFROM.xlsx").Worksheets("ANALYSIS")
    Set wsTarget = Workbooks("COPYTO.xlsx").Worksheets("ANALYSIS")

    wsSource.Range("A27:DE10000").Copy Destination:=wsTarget.Range("A27:DE10000")

End Sub
```